# PhoneGap : CSS does not load when I change html location

Tags: html, css, phonegap

Recently I have developed a phone application using PhoneGap. I wanted to rearrange my HTML file because I have many pages for my application.
Originally, all the HTML pages are put under "WWW" folder. I have created a folder under "WWW" and put my HTML page inside. However, after I did arrange my HTML pages, I found out that the HTML pages which I have arranged in folder "WWW/html" are not able to read the CSS file from ("WWW/CSS"). Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
```

[Click here for Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9WKc.png)

Comment: check the path of css file

Comment: i have show my code and the file is in the pic

Comment: Did you try to clear browser cache and stop phonegap and run it again?